# How to calculate the Theta order of the following module as the function of n?

Tags: recursion, big-o

```
function rec (n:integer);
   begin
       if n<=1 then
           return (1)
       else
           return(rec(n-1)+rec(n-1)+rec(n-1))
   end
```

My recurrence is as follow, I am confused to express this recurrence as a function of n.
I think equation is some what like; T(n) = 3T(n-1)+2.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is clearly not python. What language are you using?

Comment: sorry, it is just a pseudo code, I just need a way to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a slightly more general version of this function:

[image]

Re-substitute this into itself multiple times to spot a pattern emerging:

[image]

After repeating the process for `m` times.

When do we stop? The *stopping condition* for this recurrence is `n <= 1`, so:

[image]

Therefore the expression for `T` becomes:

[image]

Substitute in the numbers, `a = 3, b = 1, c = 2`:

[image]

Note that we ignored any rounding for the max value of `m`, since integer rounding errors have maximum magnitude `0.5`, and thus only give a constant factor difference.